# Pass scrollview touches to parent in SwiftUI without disabling the content

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, uikit, scrollview

I have a `SwiftUI` view, which is content view of my `UITableViewCell`, inside the `SwiftUI` view I have a `ScrollView` , I want user to be able to interact with the contents of this `ScrollView` , as there are sliders and textfields inside. But I need that when the user scrolls inside this scrollview the touches get passed to `UITableView` and the entire table scrolls and not this scrollview

I have tried modifiers like

`allowhitTesting` and `disable` but they end up disabling the content also.

How can I achieve this in SwiftUI

Comment: You could pass a binding from your UITableViewCell representable to your SwiftUI ScrollView that detects changes there and then use that to make changes to your UIKIt view.